# Aggregate numeric values while there is NULL varchar values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want convert table A to table B in SQL Server 2012.

Same ID returns two different values for `Characters` columns; one is NULL and other is right value. How can I drop NULL value from the Characters column and sum other numeric values in a single row?

**Table A**:

```
ID    Amount      Character
---------------------------
1001    2000       NULL
1001    500       Delight
```

**Table B**:

```
ID      Amount     Character
-----------------------------
1001    2500         Delight
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Max for [Character]:

```
Create table #TableA ([id] int, [Amount] int, [Character] nvarchar(20))

Insert into #TableA Values(1001, 2000, NULL)
Insert into #TableA Values(1001, 500 , 'Delight')

select [ID], Sum([Amount]), Max([Character])
from #TableA
Group by [ID]
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any option other than creating table? I do not have permission to create table on database.

Comment: @Mike The Create Table was just to provide a working example. If you substitute #TableA for the name of your table, just the query statement is needed.

Comment: Thank, I tried but Max (Character) brings same data with NULL value

Comment: @Mike It shouldn't do that if there is data with the same [id] value. Please can you post your version of this query?